# MP4Box / FFMPEG concat loses audio after first clip

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

So I am certainly no expert when it comes to either of these tools, but I have a web-based project that's executing commands on an Amazon Linux server to concatenate two video files that are uploaded.

Both files are converted to mp4s first using FFMPEG, and those play perfectly in a browser after conversion:

```
ffmpeg -i file1.mpg -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -c:a aac -strict -2 -movflags faststart file2.mp4
```

Then, I attempt to combine these two resulting mp4s into a single mp4. I tried using FFMPEG to do this but to no avail. Switching to try MP4Box got me much closer: the videos are concatenated together, but the audio stops playing at the end of the first clip, and the second clip is silent.

```
MP4Box -force-cat -keepsys -add file.mp4 -cat file2.mp4 out.mp4
```

I've tried varying versions of the above command with no better results. Any input is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: info on .mp4 files using

```
ffmpeg -i file1.mp4 -i file2.mp4
```

> ffmpeg -i 1510189259715DogRunsintoGlassDoor_315a03a8e20acfc.mp4 -i
>   1510189273549NewhouseMoonMoonneverseenstairsbeforefunnydog_285a03a8e6aab25.mp4
>
> ffmpeg version N-61041-g52a2138 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg
>   developers
>
> built on Mar  2 2014 05:45:04 with gcc 4.6 (Debian 4.6.3-1)
>
> configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg-static/64bit
>   --extra-cflags='-I/root/ffmpeg-static/64bit/include -static' --extra-ldflags='-L/root/ffmpeg-static/64bit/lib -static' --extra-libs='-lxml2 -lexpat -lfreetype' --enable-static --disable-shared --disable-ffserver --disable-doc --enable-bzlib --enable-zlib --enable-postproc --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-gray --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-libvpx
>
> libavutil      52. 66.100 / 52. 66.100
>
> libavcodec     55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
>
> libavformat    55. 33.100 / 55. 33.100
>
> libavdevice    55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
>
> libavfilter     4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
>
> libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
>
> libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
>
> libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
>
> Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from
>   '1510189259715DogRunsintoGlassDoor_315a03a8e20acfc.mp4':
>
> Metadata:
>
> major_brand     : isom
>
> minor_version   : 512
>
> compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
>
> encoder         : Lavf55.33.100
>
> Duration: 00:00:04.92, start: 0.023220, bitrate: 634 kb/s
>
> Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p,
>   360x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 501 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc
>   (default)
>
> Metadata:
>
> handler_name    : VideoHandler
>
> Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono,
>   fltp, 132 kb/s (default)
>
> Metadata:
>
> handler_name    : SoundHandler
>
> Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from
>   '1510189273549NewhouseMoonMoonneverseenstairsbeforefunnydog_285a03a8e6aab25.mp4':
>
> Metadata:
>
> major_brand     : isom
>
> minor_version   : 512
>
> compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
>
> encoder         : Lavf55.33.100
>
> Duration: 00:00:18.79, start: 0.023220, bitrate: 455 kb/s
>
> Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p,
>   362x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 181:180], 320 kb/s, 29.94 fps, 29.94 tbr, 11976
>   tbn, 59.88 tbc (default)
>
> Metadata:
>
> handler_name    : VideoHandler
>
> Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo,
>   fltp, 129 kb/s (default)
>
> Metadata:
>
> handler_name    : SoundHandler
>
> At least one output file must be specified

Comment: Show complete output of `ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -i file2.mp4`.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Added info to post. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: A gross generalization is that all inputs need to have the same parameters. Recommended method is to use various filters to conform inputs before concatenation with the concat filter: this can all be done with one command. Or use one input as reference, re-encode the other to match, and use concat demuxer. I can't make a turnkey example at the moment, but there are several examples on this site that probably makes your question qualify as a duplicate, and someone may give a full answer later.